# deploy python/django app to gae

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have the "mysite/poll" app from the Django tutorial running locally and am trying to deploy to GAE. I have defined DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the wsgi.py and admin.py as

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

This is the traceback on deployment:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py",      line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
      File        "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in   _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ceemee11111/1.365096182895980177/admin.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.contrib import admin
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.util import (flatten_fieldsets, lookup_field,
      File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-          1.4/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
self._setup()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is        undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable             DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

why is the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE still undefined

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#django

You can also try add

```
env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'myapp.settings'
```

in app.yaml

Comment: Fantastic, it found the file. Thankyou. If you get a chance can you explain why this changed things. I would think that it is a timing thing with it in .yaml it is defined earlier??

Comment: I can't explain it to You, just a day before this post I had to use it to :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```